# android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: Service.startForeground() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false

Tags: java, android-workmanager, android-12

I have upgrade the Android SDK project 30 to 31 and I also used permission in manifest: . which is required for targeting SDK 28 and above.
In Android 12 I am getting the frequently below crashes on 100% background application.
Also, below Android SDK version 30, its working absolutely fine.
Thanks in Advance !

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.UploadService: android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: Service.startForeground() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false: service com.UploadService
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4949)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:310)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2296)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

I have used work manager for startForegroundService in my code, how to use workmanager for startForeground to restrict this crash in Android12 and above
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check your battery saver state, the work manager will work if the battery is not optimized.

Comment: @manoj didu resolve this issue??

Comment: Yes @Liya, To resolve this I have updated the code to use startForegroundService() only when the app is not in the background since this crash only occurred when we try to call startForegroundService() at the time our app is in the background.

Comment: Can you post your code? i have the same issue.

Comment: How to use startForegroundService() only hwne app is not in the background?